# How to list / show all built-in functions?

Tags: functions

How can I list / show all built-in functions, similar to the `:function` command which lists all (non-builtin?) functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
new | put! =getcompletion('*', 'function')->filter({_, v -> v =~# '^[a-z][^#]*$'})
```

Broken down:

- `new` - Create a new window and start editing an empty file in it
- `put!` - Put the text from a register before the current line
- `=` - The expression register
- `getcompletion('*', 'function')` - Return a list of command-line completion for all functions
- `->filter({lambda})` - filter results from the returned list of `getcompletion(...)` based on the return value of `{lambda}`
- `{_, v -> v =~# '{pattern}'}` - Lambda function that returns 1 if `v` case sensitively matches `{pattern}`, else 0
- `^[a-z][^#]*$'`

  - `^` - Start of string
  - `[a-z]` - Any lowercase letter
  - `[^#]*` - Any non-`#` character, 0 or more times
  - `$` - End of String

For more info, see:

- [:h :new](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Anew)
- [:h :put](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aput)
- [:h getcompletion()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getcompletion%28%29)
- [:h filter()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#filter%28%29)

Answer (score 3):

I found a list in `:help functions` (plural) which is sufficient if there is no command.  But it would be nice to find a corollary command to `:function` -- is there one?

The functions list is also grouped by use here: `h: function-list`. Eg. it lists `string-functions`, `cursor-functions`, and so on.

Comment: is there anything missing from the help function list or why are you looking for an additional command?

Comment: It's nice to see a list in isolation, outside the context of help.  Also, I was curious if there was a corollary function to ":functions"